# Remove duplicate url's python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to remove the duplicate url's from the file having list of url's. My bugun_url_given.txt has "http://www.bugun.com.tr/ara/Ak%20Parti/1" and it fetches all the url's and they are repeating..
It saves all the unique url's in "bugun_url_collection.tx"
here is my code:

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
import urllib2
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
try:
    text_file = open('bugun_url_given.txt', 'r')
    for line in text_file:
        print line
        soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(line))
        links = soup.select('div.nwslist a')
        for link in links:
            print link
            #unique_url = set(map(lambda url : url.strip("/ "), links))
            with open('bugun_url_collection.txt', 'a') as f:
                for link in links:
                    f.write(link.get('href') + '\n')
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
            for link in links:
                f.write(link.get('href') + '\n')
```

can become

```
            for link in set(link.get('href') for link in links):
                f.write(link + '\n')
```

In response to the comment (which is correct), let's rewrite this properly:

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
import urllib2
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))


def write_links_to_file(links):
    with open('bugun_url_collection.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.writeline(link)


def get_links_from_file(text_file):
    for line in text_file:
        print line
        soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(line))
        links = soup.select('div.nwslist a')
        for link in links:
            yield link.get('href')


with open('bugun_url_given.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    links = get_links_from_file(text_file)

unique_links = set(link for link in links)
write_links_to_file(unique_links)
```

Comment: given the code in the question; `set()` in your code won't remove all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
hrefs = []
for link in links:
    print link
    hrefs.append(link.get('href'))
hrefs = list(set(hrefs))
with open('bugun_url_collection.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(hrefs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the code that generates links from the code that saves them:

```
def generate_urls(filename, urlopen):
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(line.strip()))
            for link in soup.select('div.nwslist a[href^="http"]'):
                yield link['href']

links = set(generate_urls('bugun_url_given.txt', opener.open))
with open('bugun_url_collection.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join(links))
```

Answer (score 0):

You've nested your `for` loops, so you are traversing links `len(links)` times.

```
    links = soup.select('div.nwslist a')
    for link in links:
       ... 
       with open('bugun_url_collection.txt', 'a') as f:
            for link in links:
                f.write(link.get('href') + '\n')
```

What you really want is:

```
with open('bugun_url_given.txt', 'r') as text_file, text_file = open('bugun_url_given.txt', 'r'):
    for line in text_file:
        print line
        soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(line))
        links = set(link for link in soup.select('div.nwslist a'))
        for link in links:
            print link
            #unique_url = set(map(lambda url : url.strip("/ "), links))
            f.write(link.get('href') + '\n')
```

Comment: @ pcurry: when i used ur code, it just gives one url, infact there are 14 url's all together.. How about the remaining?